# How to combine context properties pseudovariables with strings in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I need to add a attr in knockout within a foreach like so:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: url, attr: { name: 'test[' + $index + ']' }" />
```

I need the output:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: url, attr: { name: 'test[' + $index + ']' }" name=test[0] />
```

But what I get is:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: url, attr: { name: 'test[' + $index + ']' }" name="test[function d(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return this}b.r.Va(d);return c}"]/>
```

When I just use $index like so:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: url, attr: { name:  $index }" />
```

It works

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: url, attr: { name: 'test[' + $index + ']' }" name=0 />
```

... but I need to combine it with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append brackets to $index to evaluate it, i.e. `attr: { name: 'test[' + $index() + ']' }`

Comment: I seriously thought I had tried that one.  Guess not!  Thanks!